# Get multiple properties from blueprints Vertex

Tags: titan, tinkerpop-blueprint

My problem is that com.tinkerpop.blueprints.**Vertex** class does not support multiple properties (Cardinality.**SET** or Cardinality.**LIST**). To get this option **TitanVertex** class that extends from **Vertex** must be used.
I want use **TransactionRetryHelper** to make titan DB transaction.

```
User user = new TransactionRetryHelper.Builder<User>(tw.getConnection())
    .perform(new TransactionWork<User>() {
        @Override
        public User execute(final TransactionalGraph tg) throws Exception {
            return userDao.getUser(tg, userId);
        }
    }).build().oneAndDone();
```

But in this case TransactionWork interface pass TransactionalGraph to execute method and not TitanGraph that extends TransactionalGraph. The **TitanVertex** object I can get only from **TitanGraph** but not from **TransactionalGraph**.
What is the alternative to **TransactionRetryHelper** that allows to use the **TitanGraph**?

Answer (score 0):

After more detailed research of my own problem I found the solution. In my case `tw.getConnection` returns **TitanGraph** that extends **TransactionalGraph** and it is the reason that I can cast `(TitanGraph)TransactionalGraph tg` and get **TitanVertex** from it. For example:

```
User user = new TransactionRetryHelper.Builder<User>(tw.getConnection())
.perform(new TransactionWork<User>() {
    @Override
    public User execute(final TransactionalGraph tg) throws Exception {
        TitanVertex vertex = ((TitanGraph)tg).getVertices(USER_ID, userId).iterator().next();
        User u = new User(vertex.getProperty(USER_ID));//Property USER_ID has Cardinality.SINGLE
        StringBuilder fullName = new StringBuilder();
        for (TitanProperty titanProperty : vertex.getProperties(NAME)) {//Property NAME has Cardinality.LIST
            fullName.append((String)titanProperty.getProperty(NAME));
        }
        u.setFullName(fullName);
        /*set other properties for User
        ...
        */
        return u;
    }
}).build().oneAndDone();
```